# id value not returned in response to select query as specified

Tags: onedrive

Using the new OneDrive API as described on the GitHub page, by the following statement:

```
GET /drive/root/children?select=name,size
```

> By submitting the request with the `select=name,size` query string,
>   the objects in the response will only have those property values
>   included. However, by default, the `id` value will always be returned
>   even if its not specified.

Still the problem is `id` is not returning in response by default (as claimed above on GitHub page), only those properties that are mention in select query is return in response.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in our docs. Thanks for pointing it out! This is expected behavior. When you provide a 'select' statement the API will only return the properties you ask for.

Comment: but "id" should be return irrespective of properties mention in the select query

Comment: @ankit, if you want "id" you'll need to explicitly ask for it (or not ask for anything at all and get it back with the default set of properties). The documentation was incorrect to imply otherwise, so we'll update it to make sure it's more clear.

Comment: just wanted to report it, m not using select query

Comment: I've updated the docs this morning to indicate that you should specify all fields you want returned in the ?select= parameter, including id.

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to reproduce this and the "id" is not returned.  It is returned when you include it in the query.  (i.e. drive/root/children?select=id, name, size).